# Display flex and width 50% error on iPhone

Tags: html, css

My responsive footer display correctly on Chrome and mobile debug tool but error on real iPhone.

It's a container div with 4 children div inside. It should have 2 divs in each row but in iPhone it's 1 div in first row, 2 divs in second row and 1 div in the 3rd row. Tried float left but no luck :(.

```
/*Parentdiv*/
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/*Children div*/
.col-sm-3 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Check out the image below:

[Footer on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGPVd.png)

Comment: Could you provide more code? Maybe jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes - or a link?

Comment: @ÖmürcanCengiz I use bootstrap so I don't know how to add/show the problem in jsfiddle. Could you please check the website (footer): [https://next-cart.com/](https://next-cart.com/)

Comment: @MrToad I added the url in my comment. Can you check it for me? Thank you in advance

Comment: With `display: flex;` you should use `flex-basis:` instead of `width:` on child items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown us enough HTML and CSS, so I'm just assuming.

You need to add spaces between the children with `padding`, not `margin`. Margin is ignored with flex while padding is counted for. You possibly also must add `box-sizing: border-box` to the children.

You should also check that bootstrap isn't adding anything else to it, because I'm assuming that you're using that library.

---

EDIT

I unchecked `display: table` for your before element, in Safari, and the footer behaved like you wanted. I always inspect elements and try to remove as much as possible if I get any kind of unwanted behavior.

Also, if you have to do any solve any kind of position issues with *clear-fix*, it's mainly because the original layout is depending on `float` (or `absolute`?) which is a design solution that shouldn't be used today.

[image]

Comment: No I use `padding` and `box-sizing: border-box` too. This is the website url: [https://next-cart.com/](https://next-cart.com/). You can see it in the footer. If you turn on mobile debug mode in Chrome (F12) and select iPhone 6/7/8, it's ok but broken in my real iPhone (my screenshot).

Comment: Now when you gave a link, I could at least check out the code, and I managed to reproduce the unwanted behavior in Safari. I suggest using BrowserStack to check your page in different browsers. Anyway, I found the problem and edited my original post.

Comment: I just inspected my phone in safari and agree with the above.

Comment: That css code is in bootstrap, if I remove it (display: table), the website will broken. So I chose to override it. The footer looks good now!!! Thank you a million Rickard <3